# Return all rows which are same day in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I store a date in my database as a string like this:

03/08/2013  --> 8th of march

I'm trying to select only the rows that are the same day as the current day:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_aerezona_booking WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1
                                         DAY) <= STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

The above is what I tried, but it is returning a lot of results and should only return 1.

Answer (score 2):

This should work already:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_aerezona_booking 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE('03/08/2013', '%m/%d/%Y') = CURDATE();
```

By using the `DATE_SUB` you are subtracting1 day from the current day. You're not looking at today but yesterday. Also the `<=` makes you look at yesterday and all days before that.

Answer (score 1):

Then you don't want `<=`, but you want `=`.  The former will get all results if `date` is less than or equal to yesterday's date.  I'm not sure that you even want the `DATE_SUB` either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same date as today's date then you have to use "=" operator with.

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_aerezona_booking 
WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y')= CURDATE()
```